# Assign GET variable to another in PHP when you know part of the name of the GET variable

Tags: php

I have some problems with GET variable in PHP.

I need to assign a GET variable to a normal variable in PHP, but the name of the GET variable is not always the same name.

Ex. `$telf=$_GET['t_1']`.

But can be `$_GET['t_6']`, `$_GET['t_18']`.

There's any way to assign all possible names of `$_GET['t_XX']` to another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

With preg_grep you can get all keys in `$_GET` that start with 't_'. Then you walk over these values, and print (or do whatever you want) with the key + value.

Please see this example:

```
    $keys = preg_grep("/^t_.*/", array_keys($_GET));
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        echo $key.' holds value '.$_GET[$key].PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option a bit lighter in resources is using strpos on the keys

```
foreach ( $_GET as $keys => $values ) {
    if ( strpos( $keys, 't_' ) !== false ) {
        $final_var = $values;
    }
}
```